# How to return the last n number of values corresponding to a specific category?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis

I have the following sample data.

```
Date         Category   Price   Quantity
02-01-2019  BASE_Y-20   279 1
02-01-2019  BASE_Y-21   271.25  0
03-01-2019  BASE_Y-20   276.5   2
03-01-2019  BASE_Y-21   266.5   0
04-01-2019  BASE_Y-20   272.88  14
04-01-2019  BASE_Y-21   266.5   1
07-01-2019  BASE_Y-20   270.48  29
07-01-2019  BASE_Y-21   262.75  0
08-01-2019  BASE_Y-20   270 4
08-01-2019  BASE_Y-21   264 0
09-01-2019  BASE_Y-20   270.06  31
09-01-2019  BASE_Y-21   262.85  0
```

What is a dynamic formula that I can use to return the last 5 prices corresponding to category BASE_Y-20 ? The formula must return whatsoever prices are available, if 5 values are not present, which is the challenging part. (Eg: For the given data, 270.06, 270, 270.48, 272.88 and 276.5 must be returned. If we only had 1st row, it must return 279)

I have tried sumproduct. That of course gives the corresponding prices. Offset can be availed to get last 5 data. But no way for getting last 5 prices **corresponding to a specific category that is dynamic.**

Comment: Do you have Office 365? (`FILTER` / `TAKE`)

Comment: Yes. I do have Office 365.

Comment: Then you've got 2 usable answers already. Just out of my curiosity did you want the 5 bottom values to be sorted in a certain way, or just have them shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `F3`:

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A:C,B:B=F1),1),-F2,-1)
```

Few notes:

- The latest price will be at the bottom;
- If your data is always sorted to begin with, just ditch the nested `SORT()` and use `=TAKE(FILTER(A:C,B:B=F1),-F2,-1)`;
- If no value is present at all, nest the formula in an `=IFERROR(<Formula>,"")` to return any value you'd like to display in such event.

Comment: Also a way to sort them, keeping the columns and dropping them later on. Nice alternative.

Answer (score 2):

### Last Matches From Bottom to Top

**EDIT**

- With great help from P.b, the formula got reduced to the following:

```
=LET(cData,B2:B13,rData,C2:C13,cStr,G1,rCount,G2,
    rFiltered,IFERROR(TAKE(TAKE(FILTER(HSTACK(cData,rData),cData=cStr),,-1),-rCount),""),
Result,SORTBY(rFiltered,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rFiltered)),-1),Result)
```

[image]

**Screenshot Formulas**

```
J2  =HSTACK(B2:B13,C2:C13)
L2  =FILTER(J2#,B2:B13=G1)
N2  =TAKE(L2#,,-1)
O2  =TAKE(N2#,-G2)
P2  =ROWS(O2#)
Q2  =SEQUENCE(P2)
R2  =SORTBY(O2#,Q2#,-1)
```

**Issues in the Initial Post**

- I'm not sure what drove me to the decision that the data is `A3:D13` when it is obviously `B3:B13` and `C3:C13`.
- `TAKE` will work if there are fewer rows/columns than asked for i.e. if you need five rows and there are only two, two will be returned.
- Instead of using `ROWS` with the `SEQUENCE` function and then using it with `INDEX`, it is simpler to use `SORTBY` to sort by the sequence, in this particular case descending (`-1`).

---

**Initial Post (Bad)**

**LET**

```
=LET(Data,A2:D13,cCol,2,cStr,G1,rCol,3,rCount,G2,
    cData,INDEX(Data,,cCol),rData,INDEX(Data,,rCol),Both,HSTACK(cData,rData),
    bFiltered,FILTER(Both,cData=cStr),rFiltered,TAKE(bFiltered,,-1),rRows,ROWS(rFiltered),
    fRows,IF(rRows>rCount,rCount,rRows),rSequence,SEQUENCE(fRows,,rRows,-1),
Result,INDEX(rFiltered,rSequence),Result)
```

[image]

**Screenshot Formulas**

```
J3  =INDEX(A2:D13,,2)
K3  =INDEX(A2:D13,,3)
L3  =HSTACK(J3#,K3#)
N3  =FILTER(L3#,J3#=G1)
P3  =TAKE(N3#,,-1)
Q3  =ROWS(P3#)
R3  =IF(Q3>G2,G2,Q3)
S3  =SEQUENCE(R3,,Q3,-1)
T3  =INDEX(P3#,S3#)
```

Comment: Doesn't he mean `=TAKE(FILTER (C2:C13,B2:B13="BASE_Y-20"),-5)` ?

Comment: I guess I didn't study `TAKE` closely enough to know that it will work with fewer rows. Basically, that's it, I just additionally think that the order needs to be descending e.g. `=LET(Data,TAKE(FILTER(C2:C13,B2:B13="BASE_Y-20"),-5),r,ROWS(Data),INDEX(Data,SEQUENCE(r,,r,-1)))`. Still learning from you and others. Thanks for your input, it's always welcome.

Comment: Or wrap it in SORT

Comment: @P.b Sure but *"270.06, 270, 270.48, 272.88 and 276.5"* is not sorted, it's just in descending order. I guess *order* is the wrong term, I mean from bottom to top. *Orientation* possibly?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Than SORTBY (Sequence/rows) can be helpful

Comment: @P.b You're a genius. `SORTBY` with `SEQUENCE` is a savior.

Comment: Upvoted, but I still think it doesn't really require sorting

Comment: In that case this could also be a way: `=LET(x,TAKE(FILTER(C2:C13,B2:B13="BASE_Y-20"),-5),SORTBY(x,SEQUENCE(5),-1))` or dynamic: `=LET(data,A2:D13,value,"BASE_Y-20",lastrows,5,cat,INDEX(data,,2),price,INDEX(data,,3),x,TAKE(FILTER(price,cat=value),-lastrows),SORTBY(x,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),-1))`

Comment: Is this is one of those cases where a solution started down a trail of over-complexity from which it couldn't return?